# Change the Text Position of the Collapsible Header (Jquery Mobile Collapsible)

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I am creating a website for mobile devices using jQueryMobile. I have a simple Collapsible that looks like this:

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Section</h3>
    <p>I am the Content how are you?</p>
</div>
```

I managed to change the height of the header but after changing it the Text of the Header is no longer align with the Collapsible Icon.

Is there a way to change the HeaderText Position Horizontally so it aligns with the Icon?

Because i can change the Position Vertically using `text-align: center`
Here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0p92aec2/1/) with what i have tried so far.

Comment: set the line-height of the text (same element) to the same value as the height. 10vh.

Comment: Thanks that does the trick, why did you not post this as an answer ?

Comment: maybe this could be interesting for you, too: http://howtocenterincss.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`line-height`](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-5YrZq_jPAhUJnRoKHerfD2wQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FCSS%2Fline-height&usg=AFQjCNFz8HJWaPDCzfRUUXWyQdS6jQISpg&sig2=09aGAd-J0tUnKNofBpVPoA) property to center the headline text vertically:

```
.ui-collapsible-inset .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn {
    line-height: 10vh;
}
```

If you set the line-height of an element the same as the elements height, than the text will be vertically centered. In this specific case this would be a good solution, because you only have one line of text (one word).

```css
.ui-collapsible .ui-btn {
  height: 10vh !important;
}

.ui-collapsible-inset .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn {
  color: red !important;
  /*margin-top:100px !important;*/
  line-height: 10vh;
}

.ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn .ui-btn-text {
  color: red !important;
  /*top: 10% !important;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jsfiddle.net/0p92aec2/1/%22https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
      <h3>Section</h3>
      <p>I am the Content how are you?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```